# how to set css z index as its parent z index

Tags: javascript, css

how to set the zindex value of the child div's greater than parent div. where parent zindex differs.

Answer (score 2):

Positioning contexts nest. A descendant div's `z-index` only has to be higher than other descendant divs in the same positioned ancestor in order for it to appear on top. A positioned child will appear on top of the positioned parent even if it has a lower `z-index`.

At no time is it necessary for an element to know about its positioned-ancestor's `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to know how to do this...

```
node.style.zIndex = node.parentNode.style.zIndex + 1;
```

node is the child div.

Comment: This will only work if `parentNode` sets its z-index in a style attribute.

Comment: incase what would be if i'm unable to access the parent node's div